# is there a way to convert a spring boot maven pom project to gradle?

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle

I have written a spring boot application, based on a few maven startup POM entries.
Now, this application is being merged into a larger code base, which uses gradle to do builds.
Is there a way to convert a maven based project to gradle without any major disruptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://gradle.org/migrating-a-maven-build-to-gradle/ is a good starting point

Gradle init task  will automatically convert an existing Maven one to Gradle in addition to create a new skeleton project. Try running `gradle init` from the root project directory and see whether gradle is able to convert automatically. This command parses the existing POMs and generate corresponding Gradle build files plus a settings.gradle file if it’s a multi-project build. If you’re lucky and don’t have many plugins or much in the way of customization in your Maven build then `gradle init` will do the trick.

Here’s a list of Maven features that may make the process more difficult:

- Bills of Material (BOMs)
- “import” and “provided” scopes
- Optional dependencies
- Integration tests
- Custom configurations
- Less common Maven plugins
- Custom plugins

In a nutshell, Yes automatic conversion is possible, but there are lot of catches.